# how to handle SSO second time login

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on

I use SSO for my apps.
There is a login link on my app page. For the first time, after user clicks the link will redirect to login page on cas server.
After login successfully, if the user clicks the login link on my app page again,
how to handle it? It won't redirect to the login page any more, because it has already been in a logged in status.
What I want is no matter when the user click the login link, it should redirect to the cas server login page.

Comment: You said "After login successfully" doesn't that mean that user is logged in already? Why do you again ask the user to login after he is logged in?

Comment: @anup0513  because on the portal page, the login button still there and the visitor of course can click it again.

Comment: Even if its still there why to do you want to authenticate multiple times. Doing so, you will have to handle multiple session scenarios. Are you planning to handle all that?

Comment: @anup0513 If user click the login button, what should happen? Of course should go to the login page, I think. But if already authenticated, how to login page?

Comment: Read my comment once again.. Once the user is logged in... he is **authenticated** until his **session expires** or **logged out** .. when he is already logged in . you should ideally disable the login button. Why do you want to go to login page again and again?

Comment: @anup0513 Thanks, I totally understand it, maybe it's not a good design. Our login button always be shown and clickable on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

In your login page you must to check if the user is authenticated :

```
<security:authorize access="permitAll">
   ... your form login 
</security:authorize> 

<security:authorize access="hasRole('DEFAULT_ROLE')">
   ... do a redirection to desired page 
</security:authorize>
```

Comment: more details plz !